# Cannot resolve dependencies or references in MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an error in MVC/Controllers/ProductCOntroller.cs when trying to build solution.
Need to have a reference to `SportsStore.Domain` in `SportsStore.WebUI`

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;
        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            repository = productRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

The type or namespace name 'Domain' does not exist in the namespace 'SportsStore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have set up Project dependencies for MVC (WebUI) to C# class library (Domain)
How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `SportsStore.Domain` in `SportsStore.WebUI`?.

You can do this be right clicking on the "References" folder under `SportsStore.WebUI` in the Solution Explorer and selecting "Add Reference...".

[image]

then navigate to the "Solution" Tab:

[image]

and select SportsStore.Domain.